# Windows command batch file calling variable from string in nested loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, nested

I am trying to achieve this command in a batch file loop

```
md Documents
md Spreadsheets
md Medias
md Applications
md Archives
md Scripts
md Database
md Projects
md Tutorials
```

Cleaning Up documents

```
move *.pdf  Documents
move *.doc* Documents
move *.ppt* Documents
move *.txt Documents
move *.draw* Documents
move *.msg* Documents
```

Cleaning Up Spreadsheets

```
move *.csv Spreadsheets
move *.xls* Spreadsheets
move *.xml* Spreadsheets
```

Cleaning Up Medias

```
move *.psd Medias
move *.png Medias
move *.jp* Medias
move *.gif Medias
move *.tiff Medias
move *.mp* Medias
move *.avi Medias
```

Cleaning Up Applications

```
move *.exe Applications
move *.msi Applications
move *.iso Applications
move *.vsix Applications
```

Cleaning Up Archives

```
move *.zip Archives
move *.rar Archives
move *.7z Archives
move *.tar Archives
```

Cleaning Up Scripts

```
move *.cs Scripts
move *.js Scripts
move *.css Scripts
```

Cleaning Up Database files

```
move *.sql Database
move *.bak Database
move *.accdb Database
```

Trying to achieve same this as above using FOR loop and get extensions from inner loop from SET variables like Documents Spreadsheets etc.

Varirables

```
SETLOCAL
SET Folders=Documents Spreadsheets Medias Applications Archives Scripts Database
SET Documents=*.pdf *.doc* *.ppt* *.txt *.draw* *.msg*
SET Spreadsheets=*.csv *.xls *.xml
SET Medias=*.psd *.png *.jp* *.gif *.tif *.mp* *.avi *.mov
SET Applications=*.exe *.msi *.vsix *.iso 
SET Archives=*.zip *.rar *.7z *.tar 
SET Scripts=*.cs *.js *.css
SET Database=*.sql *.bak *.accdb
```

Loop

```
FOR %%f IN (%Folders%) DO 
(
    ECHO %%f
    FOR %%e IN (%%%%f%%) DO (
        ECHO    %%e %%f 
    )
)

TIMEOUT /t 10
CLS
```

The output from the loop goes like this

```
Documents
    %Documents% Documents 
Spreadsheets
    %Spreadsheets% Spreadsheets
Medias
    %Medias% Medias
Applications
    %Applications% Applications
Archives
    %Archives% Archives 
Scripts
    %Scripts% Scripts
Database
    %Database% Database
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite close, but writing an explicit percent sign doesn't pay the bill. Use [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) instead:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET Folders=Documents Spreadsheets Medias Applications Archives Scripts Database
SET Documents=*.pdf *.doc* *.ppt* *.txt *.draw* *.msg*
SET Spreadsheets=*.csv *.xls *.xml
SET Medias=*.psd *.png *.jp* *.gif *.tif *.mp* *.avi *.mov
SET Applications=*.exe *.msi *.vsix *.iso 
SET Archives=*.zip *.rar *.7z *.tar 
SET Scripts=*.cs *.js *.css
SET Database=*.sql *.bak *.accdb

FOR %%f IN (%Folders%) DO (
    ECHO cleaning up %%f
    FOR %%e IN (!%%f!) DO (
        ECHO  move "%%e" "%%f\" 
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch was scratching my head for a long long time :D

Comment: yeah, batch variables are a bit ... well. ... unintuitive when you go beyond the most basic usage `:D`.

Comment: (!%%f!) Could you please explain this portion

Comment: please read the answer, I linked to. If you want to dive really deep into that rabbit hole, I recommend [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts). But be warned - it's heavy stuff...